# vb.net USB Port Name/Description

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, wmi, vb.net-2010

I already acquired the code for Name of the `modem`. But I don't know how to use `WMI` because I can't really understand how does it works. For now, the `code` for it is so complicated.

Can you guys help me regarding to name my port? It's RFID Reader and it's USB Port. Look for the image as reference.
[image]

This image will show you that in Left Side < I got my COM 7 port in `Modem` but In right side > I got many option to pick, because my modem opens many port. I need to know how to name my other port(RFID COM PORT) so that I dont need to guess what is the right port for it.
[image]

```
Try
        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
       "root\cimv2", _
       "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort")

        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            MsgBox(queryObj("Name"))
enter code here
        Next

    Catch err As ManagementException
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
    End Try
```

So, I change the code, and I just want the system to message me what is the open port. But, unfortunately, My RFID (Profilic USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM3) is not being shown.

**Edit**

This is the output messagebox, well as you can see guys, there's no profilic. Even though it's been plugged, and seen by Device Manager.

[image]

But If I change the code to Win32_PnPEntity it will show all peripherals, and etc. and eventually It will show the Image

[image]

Comment: *I don't know how to use WMI because I can't really understand how does it works.* maybe you should do some research. Then if/when you encounter a specific question regarding programming, ask it here.

Comment: I already researched it. In `Win32_Serialport` my USB is cannot be seen but in `Win32_PnPEntity` I can see it, it was named Profilic blah blah (COM3) It should be named after this `COM3` right? But no description found.

Comment: How does `RFIDConnected` return anything? The line `rfports = rfports & (queryObj("Name"))` uses undeclared variable `rfports`, while you have declared `Dim rfport As String = ""`

Comment: Uh,yeah. I think that one too, but in the code of my `modem` it's been modified by that. And it works, dunno. Why ._. So I want to ask how to re-create that code. Sorry, just a student.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. As you have found out `Win32_PnPEntity` is what you should be using to find emulated COM ports.